# Hide document body on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a javascript that is loaded in the document head that needs to hide the document body until all page contents have loaded. I have tried:

```
$(document.body).hide();
```

But there still appears to be a flicker in some browsers. I am using the latest jQuery library (1.6.2). Firing the event on domready does hide the document body, but causing a flicker as well.

All that I can control is what is in the javascript. I cannot manipulate the static html pages as the script is being developed as a plugin.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this post](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/avoiding-dom-flickering/). It should answer your question pretty well.

Comment: This won't work either. All that I can control is what is in the javascript. I cannot manipulate the static html pages as the script is being developed as a plugin.

Comment: I don't like to be "that guy" who points out that a question seems misguided, but in this case, I have to ask: who is driving this requirement and why? As @RobG points out below, this seems to be less usable.

Answer (score 7):

Hiding content until the page is loaded is an anti-usability feature. Some parts of the content may take while to load, meanwhile your visitors see nothing. Browsers render content as it is received because users chose that as the preferred model in the very begining.

If you persist with this approach, you must hide the content using script. Otherwise, users with javascript disabled or not available, or where the script fails to execute correctly, will never see the content.

The simplest way to hide content using script is to use *document.write* to create a style sheet, then remove it to show the content:

```
document.write( '<style class="hideStuff" ' +
                'type="text/css">body {display:none;}<\/style>');

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(
    function(){
      var s, styles = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
      var i = styles.length;
      while (i--) {
        s = styles[i];
        if (s.className == 'hideStuff') {
          s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
          return;
        }
      }
    }, 1000); // debug pause
}
```

Comment: I've tried this as well and still get a flicker on sites with lots of content.

Comment: Instead of `display:none` you could try `visibility:hidden`, as that will allow the page to be fully laid out before being shown, whereas with display it will not be laid out until made visible.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is to put all content in a container div and have a style sheet that hides it by default.  You can then show the content once everything is loaded.  There is no way to run Javascript before the default page content renders so the only way to start out hidden is with a statically defined CSS rule:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        all dynamic page content goes here
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS in a stylesheet with the page to make it initially not visible:

```
#container {display: none;}
```

And, then you can do whatever you want with javascript and when you're done building the page, you do this to make it visible:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.display = "block";
```

or in jQuery:

```
$("#container").show();
```

Comment: I wonder how we would handle a fallback for disabled javascript? I can think of a few hacks, but no matter what - I think there should be one, otherwise the content will always be hidden without js. Maybe `document.write` the CSS that hides the container, inline?

Comment: What kind of fallback are you talking about? Without JavaScript it either is visible or not, unless you are doing some crazy "hovering the whole page" thingy.

Comment: that's how i would do it. and a `container{display: block;}` in a noscript for the 2 people on the internet who disabled js

Comment: This solution will not work without JS, but this is a solution for dealing with dynamically added content and no JS means no dynamically added content anyway.  So, you'd have to describe in more detail what you're really doing when there's no JS in order for us to offer any ideas.

Comment: @aefxx yes that's the problem. without js it would stay hidden, which shouldn't be the case

Comment: There's no mention of dynamically loaded content, although this could be the case. It is naive to assume the user will have js enabled, although this will be the case 99% of the time, but it is so simple to work around so it should be considered. It falls into the "Best practices" realm, which is what we should be teaching and doing.

Comment: @Andy Well, either you want to dynamically change the documents state/appearance or not. Your choice.

Comment: Maybe possible without adding div with `body { display: none; }` and then `$('body').show ();`?

Comment: @Johnny5 - that might work, but without investing the effort into testing that in all browsers, I thought it was safer to use a container div that you know is safe.

Comment: Please note that I am not the OP of the question, I just made a comment. All I suggested is that users without js should still be able to access the page. Common web best practices. *How* that's done is up to whoever deploys it. In this case, it's not me.

Comment: @Wesley Murch - if the point of this question is how to deal with JS dynamically loaded content, then there would have to be a completely different page design for browsers with no JS.  The question does not disclose that alternate design so not much we can do to comment on it.  As for whether you choose to support browsers without JS, that is up to each web app builder.  There is no requirement to do so if it doesn't make business or practical sense for your app.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're so adamant that graceful degradation is not important to consider. There is no requirement to write valid markup either, but of course it is a best practice and what we strive for as professionals. Let's please end this discussion unless you want to move it to chat.

Comment: @Wesley Murch - I'm not going to debate this with you.  Some apps just have no point or value if there is no javascript or it's way more work than is justified by the business opportunity to try to make them do something useful if there is no javascript.  This is just a practical decision based on the particular app.  Graceful degradation is nice if practical and if worth the effort.   Most of what I work on requires javascript and that has not been a problem for the audience I serve.  Other apps may be in a different position.

Comment: Just a note: with `display:none` the browser doesn't have to do anything in the realm of rendering your content inside there (images etc. won't be "preloaded" underneath etc.) A perhaps better method would be to just hide the stuff (such as with jQuery-ui's `.ui-helper-hidden-accessible`)

Comment: Wrapping is unfortunately not an option. I may not have control over the HTML being loaded in. The script is being written as a plugin for any site; not just ones that I would be coding.

Comment: Why didn't I think of this... thank you so much... excellent, elegant and simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS and JS:

In the top of your document, below the TITLE use CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">body {visibility: hidden;}</style>
```

And after this use JS to restore the visibility:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
document.write('<style type="text/css">body {visibility: visible;}</style>');
</script>
```

Enjoy :)