# cannot hide content on page load. show/hide toggle

Tags: javascript

How can I alter the code below to hide the content on page load.

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
    for (var i= document.links.length; i-->0;) {
        var link= document.links[i];

        if (link.className=='showhide') {
            var div= document.getElementById(link.hash.substring(1));
            Toggler(link, div, true);
        }
    }

    function Toggler(toggler, togglee, state) {
        toggler.onclick= function() {
            state= !state;
            togglee.style.display= state? 'block' : 'none';
            return false;
        }
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: you need to execute this on page load???

Comment: Why don't you use CSS, i.e. ````.showHide { display: none }````?

Answer (score 0):

Code:

CSS:

```
#mango {display: none;}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="mango">
    page content.... 
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("mango").style.display = "block";
```

Refer the link below:

[Hide document body on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919236/hide-document-body-on-page-load)

Comment: Have added the tags but it doesn't seem to do anything?